# How does a loop simulation works?

Tags: list, loops, erlang

```
-module(prac).

-export([len/1]).

len([]) -> 

   0;

len([_|T]) ->

   1 + len(T).
```

So I have this code and it works, but I dont know how to simulate it properly.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "simulate"?

Comment: I mean is that I don't know how it works like that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't make any sense of your question. Can you put it in different words?

Comment: Step by step procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if you're looking for an explanation of why the code works the way it does, it goes something like this. Given the following code:

```
len([])    -> 0;
len([_|T]) -> 1 + len(T).
```

If you were to call `len/1` like `len([a,b,c])`, then you can think of it executing like:

- call `len([a,b,c])`
- does `[a,b,c]` match `[]`? no
- does `[a,b,c]` match `[_|T]`? yes, yielding `_ = a` and `T = [b,c]`
- call `len([b,c])`

  - does `[b,c]` match `[]`? no
  - does `[b,c]` match `[_|T]`? yes, yielding `_ = b` and `T = [c]`
  - call `len([c])`

    - does `[c]` match `[]`? no
    - does `[c]` match `[_|T]`? yes, yielding `_ = c` and `T = []`
    - call `len([])`

      - does `[]` match `[]`? yes
      - `len([])` returns 0
    - `len([c])` returns 1 + 0
  - `len([b,c])` returns 1 + 1
- `len([a,b,c])` returns 1 + 2

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it make sense now. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang has a debugger call `im()`

try to use it