# What are the steps in doing incrementation in erlang?

Tags: erlang, increment

```
increment([]) -> [];
increment([H|T]) -> [H+1|increment(T)].

decrement([]) -> [];
decrement([H|T]) -> [H-1|decrement(T)].
```

So I have this code but I don't know how they properly work like in java.

Comment: Pretty much as was described in your similar question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008186/how-does-a-loop-simulation-works Are you wondering how they differ?

Comment: Yes, I'm really confused T^T

Answer (score 1):

Java and Erlang are different beasts. I don't recommend trying to make comparisons to Java when learning Erlang, especially if Java is the only language you know so far. The code you've posted is a good example of the paradigm known as "functional programming". I'd suggest doing some reading on that subject to help you understand what's going on. To try to break this down as far as Erlang goes, you need to understand that an Erlang function is completely different from a Java method.

In Java, your method signature is composed of the method name and the types of its arguments. The return type can also be significant. A Java `increment` method like the function you wrote might be written like `List<Integer> increment(List<Integer> input)`. The body of the Java method would probably iterate through the list an element at a time and set each element to itself plus one:

```
List<Integer> increment(List<Integer> input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size; i++) {
        input.set(i, input.get(i) + 1);
    }
}
```

Erlang has almost nothing in common with this. To begin with, an erlang function's "signature" is the name and arity of the function. Arity means how many arguments the function accepts. So your increment function is known as `increment/1`, and that's its unique signature. The way you write the argument list inside the parentheses after the function name has less to do with argument types than with the pattern of the data passed to it. A function like `increment([]) -> ...` can only successfully be called by passing it `[]`, the empty list. Likewise, the function `increment([Item]) -> ...` can only be successfully called by passing it a list with one item in it, and `increment([Item1, Item2]) -> ...` must be passed a list with two items in it. This concept of matching data to patterns is quite aptly known as "pattern matching", and you'll find it in many functional languages. In Erlang functions, it's used to select which head of the function to execute. This bears a rough similarity to Java's method overloading, where you can have many methods with the same name but different argument types; however a pattern in an Erlang function head can bind variables to different pieces of the arguments that match the pattern.

In your code example, the function `increment/1` has two heads. The first head is executed only if you pass an empty list to the function. The second head is executed only if you pass a non-empty list to the function. When that happens, two variables, `H` and `T`, are bound. `H` is bound to the first item of the list, and `T` is bound to the rest of the list, meaning all but the first item. That's because the pattern `[H|T]` matches a non-empty list, including a list with one element, in which case `T` would be bound to the empty list. The variables thus bound can be used in the body of the function.

The bodies of your functions are a very typical form of iterating a list in Erlang to produce a new list. It's typical because of another important difference from Java, which is that Erlang data is immutable. That means there's no such concept as "setting an element of a list" like I did in the Java code above. If you want to change a list, you have to build a new one, which is what your code does. It effectively says:

- The result of incrementing the empty list is the empty list.
- The result of incrementing a non-empty list is:

  - Take the first element of the list: `H`.
  - Increment the rest of the list: `increment(T)`.
  - Prepend `H+1` to the result of incrementing the rest of the list.

Note that you want to be careful about how you build lists in Erlang, or you can end up wasting a lot of resources. The [List Handling User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html) is a good place to learn about that. Also note that this code uses a concept known as "recursion", meaning that the function calls itself. In many popular languages, including Java, recursion is of limited usefulness because each new function call adds a stack frame, and your available memory space for stack frames is relatively limited. Erlang and many functional languages support a thing known as "tail call elimination", which is a feature that allows properly written code to recurse indefinitely without exhausting any resources.

Hopefully this helps explain things. If you can ask a more specific question, you might get a better answer.